# Percentage Stacked Area Chart from Excel Spreadsheet with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a percentage stacked area chart for contents inside a human retinal cell from top to bottom, using matplotlib in PyCharm, but I just got introduced to python/coding yesterday and don't know how to convert the raw data into percentages.
I have the data in an Excel sheet I'm importing with pandas and am able to show a "normal" stacked area chart, bot not sure how or where to transform the data into percentages.

I have managed to plot out the values in a stacked area chart, looking something like this:
[Stacked Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a9Rs.png)

What I want is to show the percentage individual components make up, like in this example from anychart.com
[percentage stacked area graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deJha.png).

Here is the code I currently have cobbled together:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math


organelles = pd.read_excel('H:\\cell 1 stuff\\measurements\\testbox organelles 1.xlsx')

slices = organelles["Slice"]
outersegs = organelles["POS"]
apicals = organelles["aps"]
matrix = organelles["IPM"]
granules = organelles["gran"]

labels = ["POS", "AP", "IPM", "Granules"]

plt.title('subretinal space components makeup', fontdict={'fontweight': 'bold', 'fontsize': 14})

plt.stackplot(slices, outersegs, apicals, matrix, granules,
            colors =['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown'])

plt.xticks(np.arange(500,6250,500), rotation = 45)
plt.xlim(1000, 6000)
plt.xlabel('Slice')

plt.ylabel('$nm²$')
plt.yticks(rotation = 90)

plt.legend(labels, loc = 2)

fig = plt.figure

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to do what I wanted by summing up all the columns up and calculating the percentage each individual class has by using the following code:

```py
allorganelles = organelles["POS"] + organelles["aps"] + organelles["IPM"] + organelles["gran"] + organelles["IS"]

allorganelles = organelles["POS"] + organelles["aps"] + organelles["IPM"] + organelles["gran"] + organelles["IS"]
pos_rel = organelles["POS"].div(allorganelles, 0)*100
apicals_rel = organelles["aps"].div(allorganelles, 0)*100
ipm_rel = organelles["IPM"].div(allorganelles, 0)*100
gran_rel = organelles["gran"].div(allorganelles, 0)*100
is_rel = organelles["IS"].div(allorganelles, 0)*100

plt.stackplot(slices, apicals_rel, pos_rel, ipm_rel, gran_rel, is_rel,
            colors =['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'brown', 'pink'])
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74430789/2) to the question [Percentage Stacked Area Chart from Excel Spreadsheet with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74430789/percentage-stacked-area-chart-from-excel-spreadsheet-with-matplotlib) by the OP [hufoveconMax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20467300/hufoveconmax) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>